# Getting Invalid variance: The type parameter must be invariantly valid error for generic interface

Tags: c#, generics, covariance

I have a generic interface for which I want to support type casting to base class. Hence, I added "out" parameters to support covariance. I also added "in" generic parameters as same parameters were getting used as parameter inside a function.The interface is as shown below:

```
internal interface IA<in L1, in R1, out L2, out R2> where L1 : IX where R1 : IX where L2 : IX where R2 : IX
{

    ICollection<IY<L2, R2>> Method(IReadOnlyCollection<L1> left, IReadOnlyCollection<R1> right);
}
```

Here IA,IX,IY are all interfaces. For "ICollection<IY<L2, R2>>" I am getting th following error:

```
Invalid variance: The type parameter 'L2' must be invariantly valid on 'IA<L1, R1, L2,R2>.Method(IReadOnlyCollection<L1> left, IReadOnlyCollection<R1> right)'. 'L2' is covariant.
```

In the interface IY also I defined L1 and R1 "out" generic parameters which are of base type IX.But that also did not fix this problem. So, what is it that I am doing wrong?

Comment: It's because `ICollection` is invariant. You would need to return `IEnumerable` or `IReadOnlyCollection` instead.